# Java Scanner class fails in tokenization when 1024 character is the delimeter

Tags: java, buffer, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I've found a strange behaviour of java.util.Scanner class.
I need to split a String variable into a set of tokens separated by ";".

If I consider a string of "a[*1022]" + ";[*n]" I expect a number n of token.
However if n=3 the Scanner class fails: it "see" just 2 tokens instead of 3. I think it's something related to internal char buffer size of Scanner class.

```
a[x1022];      -> 1 token: correct

a[x1022];;     -> 2 token: correct

a[x1022];;;    -> 2 token: wrong  (I expect 3 tokens)

a[x1022];;;;   -> 4 token: correct
```

I attach a simple example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // generate test string: (1022x "a") + (3x ";") 
    String testLine = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1022; i++) {
        testLine = testLine + "a";
    }
    testLine = testLine + ";;;";

    // set up the Scanner variable
    String delimeter = ";";
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(testLine);
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(delimeter);
    int p = 0;

    // tokenization
    while (lineScanner.hasNext()){
            p++;
            String currentToken = lineScanner.next();
            System.out.println("token" + p +  ": '" + currentToken + "'");
    }
    lineScanner.close();
}
```

I would like to skip the "incorrect" behaviour, could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Probably because [`Scanner` uses an internal buffer size of 1024](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Scanner.java/#310). And it doesn't look like you can change that (although it looks as though it does grow the buffer under some circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to report the bug to Oracle, and then work around it by using a BufferedReader to read your InputStream (you'll also need the InputStreamReader class). What Scanner does isn't magic, and working directly with BufferedReader in this case only requires slightly more code than you were already using.